# Adding alt img tags to an existing php website

Tags: php, image, alt

I am currently trying to add in alt `img` tags for an existing website running the interspire shopping cart platform, I have gotten pretty close I bleieve, but i cannot seem to get it right. Any help would be grealty appreciated.

```
// Is there a thumbnail image we can show? 
$thumb = $GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_PRODUCT']->GetThumb(); 
$alttext = $GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_PRODUCT']->GetProductName(); 

if ($thumb == '' && GetConfig('DefaultProductImage') != '') {
    if (GetConfig('DefaultProductImage') == 'template') {
        $thumb = GetConfig('ShopPath').'/templates/'.GetConfig('template').'/images/ProductDefault.gif'; 
    } else { 
        $thumb = GetConfig('ShopPath').'/'.GetConfig('DefaultProductImage'); 
    } 
    $thumbImage = '<img src="'.$thumb.'" alt="->GetProductName" />'; 
} else if ($thumb != '') { 
    $thumbImage = '<img src="'.GetConfig('ShopPath').'/'.GetConfig('ImageDirectory').'/'.$thumb.'" alt=""'.$alttext.'" />';
}
```

*I have tried posting the code but it says new users cannot post image tags for some reason*

Comment: You should be able to place it as a code snippet. Just don't copy and paste it directly. Paste it, highlight it, and look for the icon with 0's and 1's to place it in code tags.

Comment: Give me a moment, I'll try it put it in there, you've got to put it in as "code", which means that it's indented four spaces. It is trying to treat your text as HTML.

Comment: I tried, it would be best if you did it as you have the original formatting. Just follow what Ian said.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have two double quotes after you open the alt attribute, then the text, then another closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

This line won't work

```
$thumbImage = '<img src="'.$thumb.'" alt="->GetProductName" />';
```

You probably want something like this

```
$thumbImage = '<img src="'.$thumb.'" alt="'.$GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_PRODUCT']->GetProductName().'" />'; 

//or as you have already set $alttext:
$thumbImage = '<img src="'.$thumb.'" alt="' . $alttext . '" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

ylebre meant: (scroll the code box to the right)

```
} else if($thumb != '') { 
    $thumbImage = '<img src="'.GetConfig('ShopPath').'/'.GetConfig('ImageDirectory').'/'.$thumb.'" alt=""'.$alttext.'" />';
}
                                                                                                        ^
                                                                                                        |
```

there is one extra " at the end!

```
} else if($thumb != '') { 
    $thumbImage = '<img src="'.GetConfig('ShopPath').'/'.GetConfig('ImageDirectory').'/'.$thumb.'" alt="' . htmlspecialchars($alttext) . '" />';
}
```

Comment: I fixed that actually before I posted this and I am still not getting alt tags im not sure whats going on but I think im starting to lose it lol

Comment: When you load the site and view the source it still comes back as a blank alt tag like 
[Code]




alt=""

Comment: is there even any content in "$alttext = $GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_PRODUCT']->GetProductName();"?

Comment: There is content in the getproductname, I am honestly just debating paying someone to fix it to get it over with.

Comment: i can only think of 2 possibilities: 1. $alttext is empty, because "$GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_PRODUCT']->GetProductName();" doesn't return the expected value, or 2. the rendering codeblock is not the one drawing the actual images. you can verify both by inserting logging statements. i recommend FirePHP.